# How to create Forecast Chart using ECharts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to create a forecast chart with Actual (a line chart) and projected values (a dotted chart). [Here](https://exceljet.net/chart/line-chart-actual-with-forecast) is an example made with Excel:
[image]

I want to create the same chart using the ECharts library but I couldn't find any example to use from their web page https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/:

It would be very helpful if there is an approach to build this chart using javascript, I don't mind using other libraries like ChartJs if they have this possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this.

```
option = {
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
},
series: [{
    data: [0, 20, 30, 45, 40, 50, 51, 52, 50, 49, 56, 55],
    type: 'line',
    smooth: true,
    lineStyle: {
        color: 'red'
    }
}, {
    data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 55, 50, 49, 48],
    type: 'line',
    smooth: true,
    lineStyle: {
        color: 'blue',
        type: 'dashed'
    }
}]
```

};

It's a very simple example but it should solve your issue. I didn't add the legenda but you should be able to do thaat without any issues.